# Java 8 lambda stream

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I am trying to do the following but it throws error. Iterate over the list and call another method passing item as parameter and return true if it matches the condition.

I have below code:

```
public boolean myMethod() {
    List<String> list1 = method1();
    list1.forEach(item1 -> {
        List<String> list2 = method2(item1);
        if(list2.stream().anyMatch(item2 -> ***item2 condition***)) {
           return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

but return statement is not allowed inside for each. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sweeper I edited my code. Please take a look. the code will be inside the method.

Comment: Have you tried using `anyMatch` instead of `forEach`? Beware of your code complexity which is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Use another `anyMatch` to "bring the return value outside":

```
return list1.stream().anyMatch(item1 -> {
    List<String> list2 = method2(item1);
    return list2.stream().anyMatch(item2 -> item2 condition);
});
```

Or more simply, use a `flatMap`:

```
return list1.stream().flatMap(item1 -> method2(item1).stream()).anyMatch(item2 -> item2 condition);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second solution using flatMap works. But in first solution, in first iteration (item1) if the return condition fails, it returns false and terminates and not moving to next iteration of item1.

Comment: @Lolly that shouldn’t happen. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Same logic as `list1.stream().anyMatch(item1 -> method2(item1).stream().anyMatch(item2 -> item2 condition))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use takeWhile

```
public static void main ( String [] args){
    System.out.println(check());
}

public static boolean check() {
    List<String> list1 = List.of("1", "2");
    var count = list1.stream().takeWhile(item1 -> {
        List<String> list2 = List.of("2", "3");
        return list2.stream().anyMatch(list2::contains);
    }).count();
    return count > 0;
}
```